# String to DOM conversion

Tags: javascript, dom, domparser

I want to convert String to DOM so that, I can do DOM comparison.

I have two text files which has entire source of 2 pages. I tried to get the source of page through return brwsr.getSource() and saved in text files. y installing DOMParser and dom-compare node module, i tried to compare two DOM files to verify mismatch. But while comparing, I am getting error like Cannod read property 'nodeName' of null

NOTE: I want to compare full DOM not any specific element.

```
var compare = require('dom-compare').compare;
var reporter = require('dom-compare').GroupingReporter;
var DOMParser = require('xmldom').DOMParser;    
this.Given(/^I compare the source page$/, function () {


var expected = relativePath.resolve('tests/acceptance/wdio/TestData/source.txt');
var actual = relativePath.resolve('tests/acceptance/wdio/TestData/source1.txt');        
    var holder1= new DOMParser().parseFromString(expected);
    var holder2= new DOMParser().parseFromString(actual);
    result = compare(holder1,holder2);
    console.log(result.getResult());
});
```

Comment: Check what holder1 and holder2 is maybe there is error in you xml and you have silent error and parser return null.

Comment: You need to make sure they are valid first (just an example): `result = holder1 && holder2 ? compare(holder1, holder2) : fasle`

Comment: Can you help me with code to extract source of any 2 pages and compare there DOM? This is how i am extracting the source : this.Given(/^I take source of the page$/, function () {
        var brwsr = this.client;
        return brwsr
            .getSource()
            .then(function (source) {
                fs.writeFile("tests/acceptance/wdio/TestData/source.txt", source);
            });
    });